# Como desabilitar um commandButton no PrimeFaces de acordo com o retorno de um método boolean implementado no bean?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu tenho um botão para deletar um arquivo que eu só quero que apareça para o usuário se a minha classe tiver registros.
Segue o código dele:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
value="Excluir"
actionListener="#{deParaBean.deletar}"
oncomplete="PF('dlg1').hide"
update=":mainForm"
disabled="#{deParaBean.temRegistros}"
ajax="false"/>
```

Eu quero que a propriedade disabled dele receba true ou false de acordo com o método temRegistros que eu implementei no meu bean. Segue o código dele:

```
public boolean temRegistros(){
        if (itemParceria == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Porém, quando eu inicio o servidor e subo a aplicação, antes mesmo de renderizar a tela, aparece o seguinte erro pra mim:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /pages/dePara.xhtml @111,23
>   disabled="#{deParaBean.temRegistros}": The class
>   'br.com.parceria.bean.DeParaBean' does not have the property
>   'temRegistros'.

Alguém sabe o que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: Tenta mudar o nome do método para getTemRegistros, e mantém o disabled="#{deParaBean.temRegistros}"

Answer (score 0):

No "disabled" tu deve referenciar uma propriedade da tua classe e não um método.

Então, na tua classe, crie a propriedade "temRegistros":

```
private Boolean temRegistros;
```

Crie o get e set para essa propriedade.

E modifique teu método para que fique assim:

```
public boolean temRegistros(){
    if (itemParceria == null) {
        this.temRegistros = false;
    } else {
        this.temRegistros = true;
    }
}
```

Seria bom escolher um outro nome para o método. Assim fica mais fácil para diferenciar o método da propriedade.

Não esqueça de atualizar o componente usando o "update" após executar o método que verifica se existem registros.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que *disabled="#{deParaBean.itemParceria == null}"* já resolva seu problema.